# add image with points svg canvas

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas

I have a number of points. I want to implement in the image of my canvas , I do the following :

```
       for(var i = 0; i< coordsFinals.length; i++){
            xPoints[i] = {x:coordsFinals[i].x+50, y:coordsFinals[i].y+50};
        }
        var cFinals = xPoints;
        //console.log(cFinals);
        var clipShape = new fabric.Polygon(cFinals,{
            left: 15,
            right: 15,
            top: 0,
            fill:'#FFF',
            opacity: '0',
        });
        var pugImg = new Image();

        pugImg.onload = function (img) {
            var pug = new fabric.Image(pugImg, {
                width: imgWidth,
                height: imgHeight,
                top: imgTop,
                left: imgLeft,
                clipTo: function(ctx) {
                    clipShape.render(ctx, true);
                }
            });
            canvas.add(pug);
        };
        pugImg.src = imgI.src;
```

but when the image is added to the canvas , this does not appear as it should be taking the dot I send her, as if it were all from the central point , someone could tell me how I can make the picture really see the point . as if we put svg coordinates to an image , it's pretty much what I want to do , but in the canvas .
From anetemano thanks .

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of first glance, is that the `{x:coordsFinals[i].x+50, y:coordsFinals[i].y+50}` might need to be `{x:coordsFinals[i].x-50, y:coordsFinals[i].y-50}`. I'm assuming that the image is 100 wide, and that the `+50` was an attempt to correct that. If not, your going to have to explain more.

Comment: In fact no matter if I add any number or you rest when you draw the result always the same. My image on the canvas not taken correctly

Comment: Could you go a little more in depth in how its different than you want? Is it big or small? Does it move? If so which direction? etc.

Comment: Upon add image to canvas, with the coordinates, these do not take the correct position, if the points are that the image is drawn on the left, right, up or down, side always focused, that's what no desire because the courts do about the figures, then when sending the canvas, this does is send all my coordinates from the center, so no matter much where trimming always send my flock to downtown.

Comment: Ok, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around what you are saying. Is (0,0) at the center of the page or a corner?